# PHP | Добавление записи в MySql

Tags: php, mysql, request, insert

Есть код.

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
        or die("Ошибка: ".mysqli_error($link));
    if(isset($_POST['category'], $_POST['food'], $_POST['price'])) {
        $category = trim($_POST['category']);
        // Получить id категории
        $id_good = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE name = '$category;'"))[0]
            or die("Ошибка: ".mysqli_error($link));
        $food = trim($_POST['food']);
        $price = trim($_POST['price']);
        $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO goods(id_goods, food, price) VALUES('$id_good', '$food', '$price');")
            or die("Ошибка: ".mysqli_error($link));
        echo "Новая запись была успешно добавлена!";
    }
?>
```

Есть post-форма, от которой я получаю элемент списка `category`, название товара `food` и её стоимость `price`.
Поскольку таблица товаров имеет внешний ключ таблицы категорий, я ищу уникальный id этой категории по её названию(имя тоже уникально, одно на таблицу).

***Вопрос - правильно я сделал поиск по имени? Есть еще варианты?***

***Дальше, `mysqli_query` обязательно возвращает всегда что-то, даже если это insert, delete, update запрос?***

> Ну и самое главное - запись НЕ
>   добавляет новый продукт...где я облажался, товарищи?)

Comment: если запись не добавляется, то всегда будет ошибка. если ошибки нет, то запись добавляется. Следовательно, кое-кто заблудился в двух соснах, и не может разглядеть либо сообщение об ошибке, либо запись в БД. Либо не осилил сделать нормально форму в хтмл

Comment: $id_good = mysqli_fetch_array Тут проблема